# Can readers download zip files from WordPress sites?

Tags: customization

Is it possible to store zip files on WordPress and make links to them such that readers can download the files? I am thinking specifically of zip files that contain Mathematica applications (notebooks, computer code and documentation) and which may be 5 to 15 MB in size.

Or should such files be stored at Dropbox (say) and links made from WordPress?

Comment: You should upload in Dropbox and provide link in WordPress.

Comment: If you use a service that provides file downloads (whether that's a commerce system or a simpler plugin), you could store on your server and just use that link for what the user has access to.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the files to the media library. Then copy the links within an entry or wherever you prefer. Clicking on the link, the user can download it.

Comment: Many thanks for all the answers. If I go the WordPress route I'll try the Media Library and if I have trouble I'll fall back on Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.
But it will create link like yoursite.com/wp-content/date/month/file.zip

You can even do this by plugin Download manager : https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/

It will be easy to use and maintain